# Скачать загруженный пользователем файл JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, файлы, fileupload

Суть проблемы.

Есть `<input type="file">`. Пользователь кликает и выбирает файл. После выбора файла появляется кнопка "download" при клике на которую начинается скачивание только что выбранного файла. Как именно начать скачивание только что выбранного файла?

Можно, конечно, после клика на "download" ajax'сом сохранять файл на сервере и потом отправлять скачивать на клиенте и удалять через время на бэке, но это мне кажется бредом. Однако клиент требует такой функционал.

Я в замешательстве, быть может у кого есть идеи?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Пользователь кликает на <input type="file">, открывается окно для выбора загружаемого файла, пользователь выделяет в этом окне файл и нажимает "Выбрать". Это всё встроено в браузер.

Мне же нужно добавить на страницу кнопку, после клика которой начинается скачивание только что загруженного (выбранного) файла

Comment: Делаете blob, отдаете на скачивание браузеру.

Answer (score 3):

Для локальной страницы и файлов срабатывает такой вариант:

```js
let oInputFile = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

oInputFile.addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
  let aFiles = ev.target.files;
  if (aFiles) {
    let oLink = document.createElement("A");
    oLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(aFiles[0]);
    oLink.innerText = 'Скачать';
    oLink.setAttribute('download', aFiles[0].name);
    document.body.appendChild(oLink);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Для выбора нескольких файлов:

```js
let oInputFile = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

oInputFile.addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
  let aFiles = ev.target.files;
  if (aFiles) {
    for (let i = 0; i < aFiles.length; i++) {
      fAddLink(aFiles[i]);
    }
  }
});

function fAddLink(oFile) {
  let oWrap = document.createElement("DIV");
  oWrap.innerHTML = `<span class="txt">${oFile.name}</span>`;

  let oLink = document.createElement("A");
  oLink.className = 'dnl';
  oLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(oFile);
  oLink.setAttribute('download', oFile.name);
  oWrap.insertBefore(oLink, oWrap.firstChild);

  let oSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
  oSpan.className = 'del';
  oSpan.onclick = function() {
  console.log(this.nextElementSibling.href);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.nextElementSibling.href);
    this.parentElement.remove();
  }
  oWrap.insertBefore(oSpan, oWrap.firstChild);

  document.body.appendChild(oWrap);
}
```

```css
div{height:24px;line-height:24px;margin:4px 0}.del,.dnl{position:relative;margin:1px 3px 4px;display:inline-block;height:18px;width:18px;cursor:pointer}.del:hover,.dnl:hover{filter:drop-shadow(0 0 1px black)}.txt{vertical-align:top;margin-left:5px}.del::before,.del::after{content:'';position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;width:14px;border:1px solid red}.del::before{transform:translatex(-50%) rotate(45deg)}.del::after{transform:translatex(-50%) rotate(-45deg)}.dnl{height:8px;box-sizing:border-box;border:2px solid blue;border-top:none}.dnl::before,.dnl::after{content:'';position:absolute;bottom:100%;left:50%}.dnl::before{width:9px;border:1px solid blue;transform:translate(-50%,-1px) rotate(90deg)}.dnl::after{height:5px;width:5px;border-left:2px solid blue;border-bottom:2px solid blue;transform:translate(-50%,2px) rotate(-45deg)}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple>
```

Comment: После `URL.createObjectURL(aFiles[0])` надо освобождать память.

Comment: @UModeL Проверил, всё отлично работает

Answer (score 1):

Берем файл, переводим его в objectURL, сохраняем.

```js
function download() {
  const file = inputFile.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = file.name;
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

```html
<input id="inputFile" type="file">
<button onclick="download()">Download</button>
```

Comment: Кнопка `Download` должна появляться после выбора файла.

Comment: @UModeL надеюсь, ТС сам сможет это реализовать :)